# Return value from async / await function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm a little confused on how this async / await works

I have some functions like so

```
async getDataFromDB() {
  let response = await fetch('...');
  let data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

async getData() {
  if (...) {
    let response = await this.getDataFromDB().then((res) => {
       let response = await this.returnHello();
       return response;
    });
    return response;
  } else {
    // ... 
  }
}

returnHello() {
  return 'hello';
}
```

now when I `console.log(getData())` It should return `'hello'` but instead it returns `Promise {<pending>}`

Essentially my desired result is

```
const something = this.getData();
```

and the string is set in something correctly

Comment: Note that functions marked as `async` always returns a promise. So you need to either do: `getData().then(console.log)` or `async () => console.log(await getData())`

Comment: "*It should return 'hello'*" - no, it *should* return the promise it returns, because an `async function` is asynchronous and cannot return the future result immediately. (It doesn't block of course). Your desired result is not achievable, you need to use `await` or `then`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`async` functions *always* return promises. `async`/`await` exists to simplify the syntax of working with promises, not to eliminate promises.

The code that's using your `async` function will need to call `.then` on the promise, or be an `async` function itself and `await` the promise.

```
this.getData()
  .then(something => {

  });
```

```
const something = await this.getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

let's try

```
async showData(){
  console.log(await getData())
}
```

and run with

`showData()`

or put `console.log(response)` before `return response;` in `getData()` function.

hope that help you